# CalendarDatePicker.SetDisplayDate not working and overwritting style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-10-universal

I needed to edit the design of the `CalendarDatePicker` and of the `CalendarView` that contains the first one. 
For example I have deleted the icon that appears aside of the `PlaceHolderText` or I have set the foreground of itself to blue instead of black.

What happens is that `SetDisplayDate`does nothing and when I set the Property `Date`, the foreground color of the `PlaceHolderText` is overwritten.

This is the `CalendarDatePicker`:

```
    <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="datePicker" 
                        Grid.Column="1" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        BorderThickness="0" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        Background="White" 
                        Style="{StaticResource CalendarDatePickerStyle1}"
                        IsCalendarOpen="False" 
                        Foreground="#FF1729CA" 
                        DateFormat="{}{day.integer(2)} - {month.full}" 
                        Closed="datePicker_Closed"
                        IsTodayHighlighted="False"/>
```

In the template of the `CalendarDatePicker` there's a `CalendarView`, in my case I've replaced the default with the following:

```
<CalendarView VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Height="288" Width="360" 
              Style="{StaticResource CalendarViewStyle2}"
              CalendarViewDayItemChanging="cView_CalendarViewDayItemChang"
              DisplayMode="Month"
              FirstDayOfWeek="Monday"/>
```

The style of both objects it's irrelevant as I've just barely edited the design of the headers.

I've tried to set this previous properties in the `CalendarDatePicker` since it also has them but they have made no effect, so I'm wondering if it's not a problem of the object itself...

Another thing that doesn't behave as it should is the style of the `TextBlock` that shapes the `PlaceHolderText` of the `CalendarDatePicker`. It's defined as following:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="DateText" 
           FontFamily="ms-appx:/Fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf#Montserrat"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           Foreground="#FF1729CA"
           FontSize="22.667"
           Padding="12, 0, 0, 2"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

But when the property `Date` is set, the foreground of the previous `Text-Block` switches to black and I don't understand why.

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would help if you could [edit] your question to include the relevant bits of code. A lot of users (such as me) cannot access specific sites while on a work network, or do not like to have to leave Stack Overflow to view code.

Comment: @Rachel thanks for your suggestion! I've edited the question :)